# dplyr: Renaming multiples columns by regular expression

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset has these variables:

```
> colnames(sample)
 [1] "gender"                  "age"                     "partyID"                
 [4] "treatment_rand"          "treatment_bias"          "y_randT"                
 [7] "y_biasT"                 "y_randConti"             "y_biasConti"            
[10] "factor.sample.partyID.1" "factor.sample.partyID.2" "factor.sample.partyID.3"
[13] "factor.sample.partyID.4" "factor.sample.partyID.5" "factor.sample.partyID.6"
[16] "factor.sample.partyID.7" "factor.sample.partyID.8"
```

I would like to remove `factor.sample.` from all columns. I tried this code but got an error.

```
> sample %>%
+   rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), gsub("factor\\.sample\\.", "", names(.))))
Error in select_impl(.data, vars) : 
  found duplicated column name: factor.sample.partyID.1, factor.sample.partyID.2, factor.sample.partyID.3, factor.sample.partyID.4, factor.sample.partyID.5, factor.sample.partyID.6, factor.sample.partyID.7, factor.sample.partyID.8
```

**How can I do it using `dplyr`?**

Comment: why not just do `names(sample) <- gsub("factor.sample.", "", names(sample))`

Comment: By creating a dummy data frame with those names, your code works fine for me.

Comment: @christoph Thanks, that is my current code. Since I use `dplyr` throughout my analysis, I thought the code becomes more elegant if I could write everything using `dplyr`

Comment: @JakeKaupp Really? Could you share with us how you created the dummy data.frame?

Comment: @user51966 ah okay, I see. I'm a `data.table` person so I'm going to be able to help you, sorry!

Comment: @user51966 I used `data.frame()` with all of the provided `colnames` and set the data to random numbers.  Could you `dput(head(sample, 10))` and paste the result in here ? Also does the error persist in a fresh R session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like others, I am not getting an error when I try to use the code you provided.

However, I think you may be making things more complicated than they need to be. You should be able to skip the call to `rename` and just use `setNames` instead. Here is an example with the builtin `iris` data:

```
iris %>%
  setNames(gsub("Sepal", "Changed", names(.))) %>%
  head(3)
```

gives

```
  Changed.Length Changed.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1            5.1           3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2            4.9           3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3            4.7           3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

The same should work on yours, and may sidestep whatever issue is causing the odd error.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dplyr::rename_at()` for this:

```
library(stringr)
sample %>%
    rename_at(
          # select all variables with "factor.sample" in the name
          vars(contains("factor.sample"))
          # use stringr::str_replace to remove factor.sample.
          #   you could do the same with base::gsub()
        , funs(str_replace(., "factor.sample.", ""))
    )
```